# Chaining sqlite transaction in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, sqlite, ionic2, promise

I have chaining query(SELECT AFTER UPDATE) but in ionic2 all sqlite transaction is using callback
I already know we can execute the second query inside *then* in 1st promise query but if i have mutiple chaining the code will be harder to read.
how i can execute the second query by waiting the 1st promise **but not inside *then***? Or like implementing *Await*? or maybe have other solution for this?

There is my code now

```
  this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'qc_checking_subkon.db',
  location: 'default'
  }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      var sql = 'UPDATE t_detail SET qty_inspek='0' WHERE curr_qty_inspek > ?';            
      db.executeSql(sql ,['2'])
    .then(res => {
         var sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM t_detail'
        db.executeSql(sql2,[])
        .then(res2 => {  
         }
    ,(err)=>{
        alert('Unable to execute sql: '+JSON.stringify(err));
  }) 
    .catch(e => console.log(JSON.stringify(e)));
  })
```

i want to make `sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM t_detail'` waiting the 1st query done without writing inside *then*

Answer (score 0):

Rather than nest your promises, you could consider chaining them like this, if you prefer. Chaining is neater as at least all of the `then`'s are at the same level rather than being nested.

```
    db: SQLiteObject; // ADDED

    this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'qc_checking_subkon.db',
        location: 'default'
    })
        .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
            this.db = db; // ADDED
            var sql = 'UPDATE t_detail SET qty_inspek='0' WHERE curr_qty_inspek > ?';
            return db.executeSql(sql, ['2']); // <== NOTE THE RETURN HERE
        })
        .then(res => {
            var sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM t_detail'
            this.db.executeSql(sql2, []) // ADDED 'this'
                .then(res2 => {
                }
                    , (err) => {
                        alert('Unable to execute sql: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                    })
                .catch(e => console.log(JSON.stringify(e)));
        });
```

Comment: thank you for your respond..except this way,can i use promise.all()? if can how to use it?

Comment: Promise.all will run all of your asynch operations and wait for them all to complete, but there's no guarantee about what order they will run in. If you want to do things in a certain sequence, you'll have to chain the thens.

Comment: i see.i used your chaining on my code it worked.now im wondering how to break the chain if use my own condition?